# Why NETCONF standard distinguishes YANG models and configurations?

Tags: networking, netconf

I'm not a professional network engineer and have poor experience with NETCONF. Could you please explain to me why standard requires two different files with different extensions (xml/json and yang) to configure a network device?

According to information that I've found on the internet YANG model is intended to set a "blueprint" of configuration. They say that yang is a good DSL for creating hierarchy. And configurational data itself located in xml/json configs. Why not use only XML-based config? XML is very good language for creating and maintaining hierarchy and contains essential data for configuring device.